# Spring Web Flow 3 Development Abandoned?

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, springsource

Does anyone have any information on Spring Web Flow 3 status?

Here are a few relevant links that support my sense that springsource has essentially abandoned the project:

1)[Official roadmap](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWF#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project:roadmap-panel) indicates they are missing milestones by over a year now with no update to the roadmap.

2)[Forum thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?86858-Discuss-Spring-Web-Flow-3-Development) filled with these questions ignored by Keith Donald and Spring team.

3)[Official Download page](http://www.springsource.org/download) says the latest release is 2.2.1 but is actually 2.3 so that is not even being kept up-to-date anymore.

While Web Flow version 2 I'm sure is a great product, the issues above are all obvious red flags when it comes to evaluating an open source product -- as well as evaluating the company behind that project. Am I simply missing some communication channel where all this has been discussed in detail before? I find it hard to believe that springsource, a company that seemingly had their act together, would be this negligent with one of their flagship products.

Comment: It definitely seems so: https://fisheye.springsource.org/graph/spring-webflow. On the other hand, I would never call Spring Web Flow a flagship product of SpringSource though and I don't think anyone from SpringSource ever did.

Comment: I have a feeling they had to radically change everything so that it will work with HATEOAS too

Answer (score 3):

They just added a graphical web flow editor into STS.  See [this InfoQ post](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/06/martin-lippert-sstoolsuite-2-6).  Also, I just checked JIRA and Fisheye and it looks like there's bug fixes going into a 2.3.1 coming that corresponds with Spring 3.1.   So I don't think it's abandoned, it's just not getting new features.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to mention that the **latest version (2.3.1) of Spring Web Flow** was released on **Mar 27, 2012**. See the changelog file: http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/changelog.txt