# Spring Web Flow config for SpringFramework 3.0 or alternatives?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I would like to know, whether spring web flow supports springframework 3 release. 
According to the official documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/ch10s02.html, spring 2.5 is used (config file), but as was mentioned [stackoverflow:spring-3-spring-web-flow-2-dependencies-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462573/spring-3-spring-web-flow-2-dependencies-problem) it should work with the springframework 3, so does it mean documentation is not up-to-date, the same is for spring web flow samples, where spring 2.5 is also used.
So, if it supports, the right config header should be?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config- 2.3.xsd">

</beans>
```

Is it so?

And of course, question is raised: does it make sense to use spring flow for spring web mvc project? Because, as was mentioned in [Spring Web Flow 3 Development Abandoned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282829) no active development for spring web flow, and what is the available web flow support alternative for spring/spring mvc based project, in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It is definately not abandoned. I have successfully used SWF 2.3 with Spring 3.1 - no problems here.

As an alternative you could try to use JSF with its page navigation support.

Comment: Could you, please, provide your web flow config? I need only the header, you can obviously, skip the rest.